# Prefijos Telefónicos(resuelto)

Tags: javascript, function

Espero estén EXCELENTE... estoy estudiando netamente autodidacta y realizando varios ejercicios para ingresar a un Bootcamp Full Stack en un par de meses. Todos los días hago el sacrifico de dedicarle mínimo 2 horas a esto y siento que estoy un poquito mas desenvuelto. Quiero compartirles el ejercicio y mi solución para leer sus opiniones, con la intención de aprender y mejorar.

```
 /*var prefijos = [54, 55, 56, 57, 58]
var paises = ["argentina", "brasil", "chile", "colombia", "venezuela"]
Debés crear una función llamada `validarPrefijo` que reciba un número por parámetro.
Deberá:
1. Generar un objeto desde dos arreglos dados. Deberá tener como propiedades,
los números de prefijos, y como valor, el país correspondiente a cada prefijo.
ejemplo :
{
54: “Argentina”,
55: ”Brasil”,
56: ”Ecuador”,
57: ”Bolivia”
}
2. Validar si los dos primeros números del pasado por parámetro existen en el
objeto de prefijos telefónicos. En caso de ser correcto, deberá retornar “Este
número pertenece a X”.
3. En caso de ser incorrecto deberá retornar “El número no pertenece a nuestros
países”
Ejemplo:
- validarPrefijo(“5412345678”) debe retornar “Este número pertenece a Argentina”
- validarPrefijo(“5712345678”) debe retornar “Este número pertenece a Bolivia”
- validarPrefijo(“8012345678”) debe retornar “El número no pertenece a nuestros
países”
 */

const validarPrefijo=(num)=>{
    const regex = /^[0-9]*$/;//regex para num
    const validarNum=regex.test(num) //validacion de num
    let principio=[num[0]+num[1]] //lo que se me ocurrió para validar los 1eros 2 caracteres
    var paises = ["ARGENTINA", "BRASIL", "CHILE", "COLOMBIA", "VENEZUELA <3"];
    var prefijos = [54, 55, 56, 57, 58];
    var objeto={};
    //creo el objeto
    for (i in prefijos){
    Object.defineProperty(objeto,prefijos[i],{value:paises[i],enumerable:true})
                                                            //enumerable para leer los datos dentro
    }

    //validaciones:
    if(num.length<=0)return console.error("Los datos ingresados no pueden estar vacios")
    if(validarNum==false)return console.error("Los datos ingresados deben ser SOLO numeros")
    if(typeof num!=="string")return console.error("Ingresa los datos en forma de String")
    if(num.length>12){return console.warn("El numero ingresado es muy largo")}

    let key=Object.keys(objeto)     //Guardo las keys del objeto para compararlas 
    if(key.includes(`${principio}`)){ //plantillas de cadena...la mejor opcion?
        return console.log(`${num} \nEste numero pertenece a: "${objeto[principio]}"`);
    }else return console.error(`"${num}" no pertenece a nuestros paises`)
       
}

validarPrefijo("5411224466")
```

Solo quiero saber si es "lo mas optimo" en cuestión de ejecución.
De antemano les agradezco mucho, tremenda comunidad hay acá.

Comment: La manera más eficiente de hacerlo es guardar un objeto cuya clave sea el prefijo y cuyo valor sea el pais. Guardar dos arrays diferentes para luego estarlos iterando es sumamente ineficiente cuando en realidad simplemente puedes declarar el objeto literal. Iterando por elementos de un arreglo estás elevando la complejidad del problema a O(n) cuando con un objeto puedes hacerlo con complejidad O(1).

Comment: Lo que podría ser una operación como `prefijos[prefijo]`  para saber el país lo estás convirtiendo dos un bucles con `Object.keys(objeto)` y con  `key.includes()`. Por otro lado, no me hace mucho sentido el `return console.log(..)`, básicamente estás retornado `undefined`.

Comment: Hola Jaime, estoy intentando modificar mi ejercicio sin embargo no logro llevarte el paso en lo que me aconsejas. Serias un poco mas ilustrativo?

Comment: Bueno por lo que leo en los comentarios de tu código, el ejercicio te forzó a crear los dos arreglos y a iterarlos. De cualquier manera, [acá](https://gist.github.com/JaimeMenendez/f9e8369395a3d3dee79fef8055aa3a46) te adjunto la manera más eficiente de hacerlo, para que lo tengas en cuenta si te enfrentas a un problema como este.